# How can I control the size of the numbers on my slider in Shiny?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a good looking Shiny app, but the numbers on top of the slider are tiny.

[image]

How can I increase the size of these numbers?

I know already that it will involve some CSS. But I don't know how I can set a class for these numbers...if there was something I could 'hook' on, then I could probably figure out the rest.

As it is, I tried to include a class called `changeSize` as such:
`column(3, h1(class="changeSize", sliderInput(inputId="age", "Age Range", min=32, max=99, value=c(50, 85), step=1)))` 
but this only allows me to control the size of the text, 'Age Range', using some CSS

```
.changeSize label {
    font-size: 15pt;
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a style tag to the header argument in shiny::navbarPage in ui.R did it for me:

```
navbarPage(..., 
  header=tags$head(tags$style(type='text/css', ".irs-grid-text { font-size: 20pt; }")))
```

Comment: how did you find out that the slider text is called ".irs-grid-text"? Is there any documentation available on how to access all the various shiny elements by names?

Comment: Using Chrome: right click -> inspect element: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles